# Full Text indexing Multiple languages

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-indexing

My DB stores content in three languages (English,French & Arabic) I have full text indexing enabled for few tables and would like to know few best practices:
1. When show I us language neutral indexing?
2. Can I Index Arabic? I don't see Arabic in the Indexable language!
3. should I have separate indexes for each language? (Each of my tuple has all the three languages)

Any Idea and suggestions are welcome.